# Loading inline content from an iframe

Tags: ajax, iframe, colorbox

First of all, I had all my buttons which opened the Colorbox using the "ajax" class. That class however caused me many problems:
1-When I open one window, it will appear, when I close it and re-click the same button, it will be loaded twice (so I need to click twice to close)
Is there a fix for this?

What I have done for the moment:
Use iframes; my only problem now is I cant load the other colorboxes that are linked in that iframe. I am using the inline class.

Let me re-phrase that: I click on button "generate" it opens first colorbox with the iframe class. Inside that iframe I have a "generate_2" button which has inline content. Once I click that second button nothing happens. This used to work when I had the first button set to ajax.

What can I do?
thanks!

Comment: Is there JavaScript in the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. Since JavaScript cannot affect iframes, you must add the JavaScript code inside a script tag in the iframe page itself.

Answer (score 0):

> when I close it and re-click the same button, it will be loaded twice (so I need to click twice to close) Is there a fix for this?

I'd wager you are using ajax to open a complete HTML document, aren't you?  You shouldn't be doing that.  It's not valid HTML to nest one HTML document inside another, and you are causing the scripts from both to be applied to the original document.  Each time you load that content, those scripts are being loaded and executed all over again.